# How would i check to see the number of key => value pairing differences in arrays that have similar orders?

Tags: php, arrays

For example, if I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

$array2 = array('a', 'c', 'b', 'd');
```

Assuming that both arrays have similar orders (based on the last and first values), how would I check to see that are two differences in their key value pairings, in their defined orders?

As well as this, how could I return (possibly through another function), where exactly these differences are, by key?

Comment: Loop over both arrays and compare their elements?

Comment: I think you are looking for `array_diff_uassoc` there is an example of exactly what you are looking for on this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using array_diff_assoc() with a callback will give you a result of the difference but only with the first arrays keys and values returned. If you want the second arrays differences, reverse the order of the parameters

```
$array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

$array2 = array('a', 'c', 'b', 'd');

function key_compare ($a, $b) {
    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b)? 1:-1;
})

print_r(array_diff_uassoc($array1,$array2, "key_compare");
```

Result... Array ( [1] => b [2] => c )

Reversed...

```
print_r(array_diff_uassoc($array2,$array1, "key_compare");
```

Result... Array ( [1] => c [2] => b )